# Is "gasping" an adjective, adverb, or neither?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Is "gasping" an adjective, adverb, or neither?

Comment: Never an adverb or an adjective, but it can be a noun in "The gasping eventually stopped", and of course a verb, as in "The gasping athlete" / "The athlete was gasping for air".

Answer (score 0):

"Gasping", the -ing form of the verb "gasp", can function as a gerund (a noun) or as part of a conjugated verb.

The gasping was audible. (noun)

The man is/was gasping audibly. (part of a progressive verb).

Comment: In "the gasping man ...", "gasping" is best analysed as a verb, not an adjective.

Comment: No, it is a present participle used as an adjective. See: https://www.dailywritingtips.com/present-participle-as-adjective/

Comment: I disagree. It can't be modified by "very", nor can it occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs like become (* "It became quite gasping"), or to complex-transitive verbs like "find" (* "I found it quite gasping"). It's a verb, the same as, for example, "sleeping" is in "a sleeping child". The site you provided a link to is hardly a reliable grammar resource.

Comment: Well, thank you, I will look into that further.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found a more reliable source: https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-participial-adjective-1691486    Is there a better label for that use than just "verb"?  Also, I have removed the incorrect information from my answer.

Comment: I've looked at some discussions of -ing form category on Stack Exchange (in which you were a participant), and it seems the category of this use is controversial. What do you think about "The man was almost gasping."?

Comment: "The man was almost gasping" is the progressive (continuous) aspect, where "gasping" is a verb present participle.